# Difference between setting aes in ggplot function or in a geom?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how it's working to set aesthetics in `ggplot`. How it's possible to know where to put the `aes` in `ggplot`?

Consider this code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, 
            mapping = aes(x = wt, 
                          y = mpg, 
                          colour = "blue"))
# A basic scatter plot
hello = p + geom_point(size = 4) + ggtitle(label = 'Hello')
goodbye = p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)), size = 4)  + ggtitle(label = 'Goodbye')
col.points = p + geom_point(size = 4, color = "blue") + ggtitle(label = 'Col.points')

gridExtra::grid.arrange(hello, goodbye, col.points)
```

Here, it's possible to see that the colour "blue" is not applied to the points in the first graph (hello), and in the second (goodbye) it's getting the colour from a column. But what's the difference? The col.points example shows that the points are indeed coloured.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is that when the `aes` are set in the original `ggplot`, they are inherited by any other geom's that build on top of it. If you specify the `aes` only in a geom, it will only be used in that geom. If you use any specific `aes` in `geom`, they override the settings in `ggplot`.

In your example code, in the first instance:

```
p + geom_point(size = 4)
```

The size of the points is set to 4, and the `aes(wt, mp, colour = 'red')` is inherited from `ggplot`. In the second case:

```
p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))
```

The resulting aes is `aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl)` as the `wt` and `mpg` are inherited from the `ggplot` object, and the `colour = factor(cyl)` overwrites the `colour = 'red'`.